# Lighthouse returned error: INTERNAL: Extension result empty

Tags: javascript, lighthouse

Not sure why my website give following error when I try to test it through Page Speed Insights:

Lighthouse returned error: INTERNAL: Extension result empty. Lighthouse calling Page.navigate with https://www.maheencg.com/ Uncaught (in promise) Error: Extension timed out. No call to exit() before render timeout. at wrs.Extension.onTimeout_ (http://ghost-rider/devtools_script_api.js:5606:13) at http://ghost-rider/devtools_script_api.js:655:11

May you please help me with that? Thank you.